# How to combine entries from 2 arrays at the same position in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 dynamic ranges (one holding a field name, and one holding a position number). To make it simple, here is an example, the actual ranges contain many more entries.

```
Field     Position
SN        20
AT        8
```

I can loop through one of the ranges at a time, but not at the same time.

Using the following code, the output is:

```
SN
20
8
AT
20
8
```

```vb
Sub testarray2()
    HeadArray = [Drng_EUSUploadFields].Value
    ColArray = [Drng_EUSUploadPositions].Value

    For Each element In HeadArray
        MsgBox element

        For Each element2 In ColArray
            MsgBox element2
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
SN
20
AT
8
```

In the sample code, I used `msgbox`, but plan to use each entry as variables in prepping a worksheet. I will us `SN & 20` first, then use `AT & 8`, etc...

I hope this makes sense and is not rambling. Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You are outputing the whole of `ColArray` for *each* element of `HeadArray`.

To make it easier to see what's happing, update your code to this (show the Immediate Winow form the View menu)  The Immediate window makes it easy to see the whole output

```vb
Sub testarray2()
    HeadArray = [Drng_EUSUploadFields].Value
    ColArray = [Drng_EUSUploadPositions].Value

    For Each element In HeadArray
        Debug.Print "Outer", element

        For Each element2 In ColArray
            Debug.Print "Inner", element2
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Output from this will be

```
Outer         SN
Inner          20 
Inner          8 
Outer         AT
Inner          20 
Inner          8
```

To get your desired output

```vb
Sub testarray3()
    HeadArray = [Drng_EUSUploadFields].Value
    ColArray = [Drng_EUSUploadPositions].Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(HeadArray, 1)
        Debug.Print HeadArray(i, 1)
        Debug.Print ColArray(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

<sub>Side Note: you should use `Option Explicit` and Declare all your variables</sub>